# Switching windows in Firefox 34 hangs

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, webdriver, switch-statement

I am using Selenium webdriver 2.44 with firefox 34 on windows 7 machine. I have a script where I hover over an 'open page' icon and click it. The click opens the a new tab manually and in chrome driver 2.15. The scenario opens a new window instead of tab which I handle in firefox-34. below is the code.

```
public void switchWindow(){
    //try {

    String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();
    System.out.println("before  "+winHandleBefore);
    Set<String> windows = driver.getWindowHandles();

    for (String window : windows) {
        driver.switchTo().window(window);
        if (driver.getTitle().contains(winHandleBefore)) {
            return;
        }
    }
```

The problem I am facing is one or two tests run for more than 10,000 seconds as they look like they hang at switching the windows from parent to child. This is issue is reproducible each and every time.Has anybody seen this issue?. Is there a workaround?.Kindly let me know if additional information needs to be provided.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by closing the first window and shifting the focus back on the newly opened window. I didn't expect the fix would be this simple.
The fix works for FF-35 as well.